# Creating a unique list from a non-unique list of values

Tags: excel

I have the following list:

```
   **Customers**
    1) Patata
    2) Ntomata
    3) Karoto
    4) Ntomata
    5) Peponi
    6) Peponi
```

And I would like to create the following list:

```
**Customers**
1) Patata
2) Ntomata
3) Karoto
4) Peponi
```

I want a unique list of customer names, where each customer name appears only once.

Is that doable without VBA?

Regards

Thanasis

Comment: See here for several built in ways to do this that do not require VBA: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Comment: Use remove duplicates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. With built-in function:
   `Data > Remove Duplicates`, and pick the column

[image]

2. Use array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together):

   `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$7),0)),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian!! I wanted the second way! It worked great!

Still cannot understand the match 0 and the countif combination but I guess I will be able to find out through evaluate formula option.

I am on my Mac at the moment and this option is not available on Office for Mac.

Comment: @Thanasis, the `MATCH` function @ian0411 used first uses the `COUNTIF` function to count how many times any given value from `$A$2:$A$7` appears in any cell in `$B$1:B1` (which will grow by one row with each new cell the formula is expanded into). Then `MATCH` takes over. If `COUNTIF` previously found a value from `$A$2:$A$7` in `$B$1:B1`, then it will return a count of 1 (hence the `COUNTIF` function), not 0. Since `MATCH` is looking for a count of 0, not 1, it skips any value that has already appeared in `$B$1:B1` and returns the first value from `$A$2:$A$7` that it cannot find in `$B$1:B1`.